# Python recursion issue [leetcode problem]

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

[image]

Above is the question. It is to find all the permutation in for given array of integers(all unqiue)

**Actual Question**

I was trying out check the brute-force method permutation method(*Not looking for the optimal solution*). I found myself in this peculiar problem. **The result array used to store the permutations changed with every recursion call.** I cannot put a head around it why is that. Need help figuring it out.

I have included print() from different places of the code for debugging purpose. Let me know if you need any other information to help you reach an answer.

Algorithm walkthrough

*element_map* -> stores False for each position of the input array *[False,False,False]* in this case
*temp_result* -> stores temporary permutations in each step

1. *permutation function* iterates over every val of the input array and stores permutations in the *temp_result* array.
2. Once an element is added to *temp_result*, it marks *element_map* as True and recursively calls *permutation function* again.
3. End of recursion is if *len(temp_result) == len(nums)*. In that case, we got one permutation and we add it to result.
4. Once base case 3 is hit we set *element_map[i] = False* and pop the last val from *temp_result*

```
class Solution:
    def permute(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
        
        if len(nums) == 1:
            return [nums]
        
        result = []
        element_map = defaultdict(bool)
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            element_map[i] = False
        
        def permutations(nums, temp_result, element_map):
            nonlocal result
            print("Start result ->", result)
            print("Start temp_result ->", temp_result)
            
            if len(temp_result) == len(nums):
                result.append(temp_result)
                print(len(temp_result),len(nums))
                print("temp_result ->", temp_result)
                print("result-> ",result)
                return
            
            for i,val in enumerate(nums):
                
                if not element_map[i]:
                    element_map[i] = True
                    temp_result.append(val)
                    permutations(nums, temp_result, element_map)
                    temp_result.pop()
                    element_map[i] = False
        
        temp_result = []
        permutations(nums, temp_result, element_map)
        print(result)
```

Code Output for input [1,2,3]. Issue is the *result* keeps changing.

```
Start result -> []
Start temp_result -> []
Start result -> []
Start temp_result -> [1]
Start result -> []
Start temp_result -> [1, 2]
Start result -> []
Start temp_result -> [1, 2, 3]
3 3
temp_result -> [1, 2, 3]
result->  [[1, 2, 3]]
Start result -> [[1, 3]]
Start temp_result -> [1, 3]
Start result -> [[1, 3, 2]]
Start temp_result -> [1, 3, 2]
3 3
temp_result -> [1, 3, 2]
result->  [[1, 3, 2], [1, 3, 2]]
Start result -> [[2], [2]]
Start temp_result -> [2]
Start result -> [[2, 1], [2, 1]]
Start temp_result -> [2, 1]
Start result -> [[2, 1, 3], [2, 1, 3]]
Start temp_result -> [2, 1, 3]
3 3
temp_result -> [2, 1, 3]
result->  [[2, 1, 3], [2, 1, 3], [2, 1, 3]]
Start result -> [[2, 3], [2, 3], [2, 3]]
Start temp_result -> [2, 3]
Start result -> [[2, 3, 1], [2, 3, 1], [2, 3, 1]]
Start temp_result -> [2, 3, 1]
3 3
temp_result -> [2, 3, 1]
result->  [[2, 3, 1], [2, 3, 1], [2, 3, 1], [2, 3, 1]]
Start result -> [[3], [3], [3], [3]]
Start temp_result -> [3]
Start result -> [[3, 1], [3, 1], [3, 1], [3, 1]]
Start temp_result -> [3, 1]
Start result -> [[3, 1, 2], [3, 1, 2], [3, 1, 2], [3, 1, 2]]
Start temp_result -> [3, 1, 2]
3 3
temp_result -> [3, 1, 2]
result->  [[3, 1, 2], [3, 1, 2], [3, 1, 2], [3, 1, 2], [3, 1, 2]]
Start result -> [[3, 2], [3, 2], [3, 2], [3, 2], [3, 2]]
Start temp_result -> [3, 2]
Start result -> [[3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1]]
Start temp_result -> [3, 2, 1]
3 3
temp_result -> [3, 2, 1]
result->  [[3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1]]
[[],[],[],[],[],[]]
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations

Comment: @oskros Thanks for this. Doesn't solve my problem but is a good read.

Comment: sure, it doesn't solve the issue you have with your code. but the function can solve it much easier, and there is an explanation of how it works. you could simply do sth like `list(map(list, itertools.permutations([1,2,3])))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution

```
if len(temp_result) == len(nums):
     result.append(temp_result[:])
```

instead of

```
if len(temp_result) == len(nums):
     result.append(temp_result)
```

In the latter *result* values changes with the value of *temp_result*.

Answer (score 0):

I've written an alternative to your function.
I've tested this with Python2, but it should work with Python3 as well.

```
Arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

def permute(arr):
    myresult = []
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        sarr = arr[:i] + arr[i+1:]
        el = arr[i]
        if len(sarr) != 0:
            a = permute(sarr)
            for result in a:
                c = [el] + result
                myresult.append(c)
        else:
            return [[el]]
    return myresult

p = permute(Arr)
print str(p)
```

`myresult` is going to be the result of the permute function.
`sarr` stands for the "smaller array".
`el` stands for Element (of the Array).

The idea is to pick an element and to concatenate each permutation of the remaining array. By using recursion the entire input array will be processed

Comment: thank you for the solution. But it is not what I was looking for. Heap's Algorithm will be optimal solution. My question is why the result variable behave the way it does in the recursion. The goal is to avoid this issue in future for other problems.

Comment: I have found the issue. Added as an answer for anyone facing the same.